# Can't UPDATE rows to be the same value as they currently are?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a procedure like

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_case_update', 'case_update' );

function case_update ( )
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $compname = $_POST['compname'];
    $casename = $_POST['casename'];
    $imageurl = $_POST['imageurl'];
    $summary = $_POST['summary'];
    $results = $_POST['results'];

    $thisAction = $_POST['thisAction'];

    $message = "";

    switch ($thisAction)
    {
        case 'add':
        {
            global $wpdb; 
            $message .= $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO cases (compname,casename,imageurl,summary,results) VALUES (" . implode(",", array("'$compname'", "'$casename'", "'$imageurl'", "'$summary'", "'$results'")) . ")")
                       ? 'Successfully added case study ' . $casename . ' to the database.'
                       : 'Error occurred when trying to add case study to database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
        case 'delete':
        {
            global $wpdb; 
            $message .= $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM cases WHERE id=" . $id) 
                      ? 'Successfully deleted case study from the database.'
                      : 'Error occurred when trying to delete case study from database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
        case 'update':
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $message .= $wpdb->query("UPDATE cases SET compname='$compname',casename='$casename',imageurl='$imageurl',summary='$summary',results='$results' WHERE id=$id")
                      ? 'Successfully updated case study.'
                      : 'Error occurred when trying to update case study in database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            $message .= 'Didn\'t recognize action.'; 
            break;
        }
    }
    die($message); 
}
```

and I've been reusing this procedure for a lot of admin panels that I'm building in my WordPress theme. What I just discovered during testing is that the `case 'update'` block is failing when the user, for whatever reason, updates to the same value. But since `$wpdb->last_error;` isn't printing any errors when that happens, I don't know exactly what the problem is.

Anyone have an explanation? And how do I fix?

Comment: if you update to the same value the sql runs in the sql server but 0 rows are affected, so if you're checking the number of rows affected........

Comment: @developerwjk Ah, I see ...

Answer (score 1):

Add a timestamp column named `updated` to your table and add a `, updated=now()` to your UPDATE statement in order to produce a non-zero value for updated rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the query() result === false. Per the [Wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#General_Syntax):

> This function returns an integer value indicating the number of rows affected/selected for SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, etc. For CREATE, ALTER, TRUNCATE and DROP SQL statements, (which affect whole tables instead of specific rows) this function returns TRUE on success. If a MySQL error is encountered, the function will return FALSE. Note that since both 0 and FALSE may be returned for row queries, you should be careful when checking the return value. Use the identity operator (===) to check for errors (e.g., false === $result), and whether any rows were affected (e.g., 0 === $result).

Comment: So checking whether the query DIDN'T fail would be `result != false` -- right?

Comment: That would be equivalent to what you have now. You need `result !== false`

Comment: I thought the opposite of `===` in loosely-typed languages is `!=` and the opposite of `!==` is `==`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have the privileges to comment yet, so have to post as an answer.
**Justin**'s answer is correct.
@**Mediocre Web Dev** As for your question in the comment. You have to use
`result !== false`.
The data type has to be the same in this case.